# unix sort groups by their associated maximum value?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, grouping, gnu-coreutils

Let's say I have this **input** file `49142202.txt`:

```
A   5
B   6
C   3
A   4
B   2
C   1
```

Is it possible to sort the groups in column 1 by the value in column 2? The desired **output** is as follows:

```
B   6 <-- B group at the top, because 6 is larger than 5 and 3
B   2 <-- 2 less than 6
A   5 <-- A group in the middle, because 5 is smaller than 6 and larger than 3
A   4 <-- 4 less than 5
C   3 <-- C group at the bottom, because 3 is smaller than 6 and 5
C   1 <-- 1 less than 3
```

Here is my **solution**:

```
join -t$'\t' -1 2 -2 1 \
 <(cat 49142202.txt | sort -k2nr,2 | sort --stable -k1,1 -u | sort -k2nr,2 \
  | cut -f1 | nl | tr -d " " | sort -k2,2) \
 <(cat 49142202.txt | sort -k1,1 -k2nr,2) \
| sort --stable -k2n,2 | cut -f1,3
```

The first input to `join` sorted by column 2 is this:

```
2   A
1   B
3   C
```

The second input to `join` sorted by column 1 is this:

```
A   5
A   4
B   6
B   2
C   3
C   1
```

The output of `join` is:

```
A   2   5
A   2   4
B   1   6
B   1   2
C   3   3
C   3   1
```

Which is then sorted by the `nl` line number in column 2 and then the original input columns 1 and 3 are kept with `cut`.

I know it can be done a lot easier with for example [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) of pandas of Python, but is there a more elegant way of doing it, while sticking to the use of [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) such as [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation), [`join`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#join-invocation), [`cut`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#cut-invocation), [`tr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#tr-invocation) and [`nl`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#index-numbering-lines)? Preferably I want to avoid a memory inefficient `awk` solution, but please share those as well. Thanks!

Comment: By the way since you are talking about performances: `cat 49142202.txt | sort -k2nr,2` is very very very bad way of doing what you think you are doing -> you do not need the cat in the first place. In both commands!!!

https://superuser.com/questions/192052/advantages-of-cating-file-and-piping-to-grep

Comment: Also note that using many pipes and running a lot of processes is not free and you have to take into account all the switching cost between processes! Last but not least, piping all the `sort` commands will slow drastically the execution on long files!!!!

Comment: @Allan Good points! I agree!

Comment: Hey, in the end what was the best solution for you?

Comment: @Allan Work is somewhat busy and I will not have time to evaluate until next weekend. I'm happy to accept your answer. Let me know what you prefer.

Comment: Take your time and evaluate it, if you do not have time you can just accept it as well :p

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comment my solution tries to reduce the number of `pipes`, unnecessary `cat` commands and more especially the number of pipeline `sort` operations since sorting is a **complex/time consuming operation**:

I reached the following solution where `f_grp_sort` is the input file:

```
for elem in $(sort -k2nr f_grp_sort | awk '!seen[$1]++{print $1}')
do 
   grep $elem <(sort -k2nr f_grp_sort) 
done
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
B       6
B       2
A       5
A       4
C       3
C       1
```

**Explanations:**

`sort -k2nr f_grp_sort` will generate the following output:

```
B       6
A       5
A       4
C       3
B       2
C       1
```

and `sort -k2nr f_grp_sort | awk '!seen[$1]++{print $1}'` will generate the output:

```
B
A
C
```

the `awk` will just generate in the same order 1 unique element of the first column of the temporary output.

Then the `for elem in $(...)do grep $elem <(sort -k2nr f_grp_sort); done`
will `grep` for lines containing `B` then `A`, then `C` what will provide the required output.

Now as enhancement, you can use a temporary file to avoid doing `sort -k2nr f_grp_sort` operation twice:

```
$ sort -k2nr f_grp_sort > tmp_sorted_file && for elem in $(awk '!seen[$1]++{print $1}' tmp_sorted_file); do grep $elem tmp_sorted_file; done && rm tmp_sorted_file
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this won't work for all cases, but if the values in your first column can be turned into bash variables, we can use dynamically named arrays to do this instead of a bunch of joins.  It should be pretty fast.

The first while block reads in the contents of the file, getting the first two space separated strings and putting them into `col1` and `col2`.  We then create a series of arrays named like `ARR_A` and `ARR_B` where `A` and `B` are the values from column 1 (but only if `$col1` only contains characters that can be used in bash variable names).  The array contains the column 2 values associated with these column 1 values.

I use your fancy sort chain to get the order we want column 1 values to print out in, we just loop through them, then for each column 1 array we sort the values and echo out column 1 and column 2.

The dynamc variable bits can be hard to follow, but for the right values in column 1 it will work.  Again, if there's any characters that can't be part of a bash variable name in column 1, this solution will not work.

```
file=./49142202.txt

while read col1 col2 extra
do
  if [[ "$col1" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$ ]]
  then
    eval 'ARR_'${col1}'+=("'${col2}'")'
  else
    echo "Bad character detected in Column 1:  '$col1'"
    exit 1
  fi
done < "$file"

sort -k2nr,2 "$file" | sort --stable -k1,1 -u | sort -k2nr,2 | while read col1 extra
do 
  for col2 in $(eval 'printf "%s\n" "${ARR_'${col1}'[@]}"' | sort -r)
  do
    echo $col1 $col2
  done
done
```

This was my test, a little more complex than your provided example:

```
$ cat 49142202.txt
A 4
B 6
C 3
A 5
B 2
C 1
C 0

$ ./run
B 6
B 2
A 5
A 4
C 3
C 1
C 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @JeffBreadner and @Allan! I came up with yet another solution, which is very similar to my first one, but gives a bit more control, because it allows for easier nesting with for loops:

```
for x in $(sort -k2nr,2 $file | sort --stable -k1,1 -u | sort -k2nr,2 | cut -f1); do
 awk -v x=$x '$1==x' $file | sort -k2nr,2
done
```

Do you mind, if I don't accept either of your answers, until I have time to evaluate the time and memory performance of your solutions? Otherwise I would probably just go for the `awk` solution by @Allan.

Comment: In doing some testing, my solution will eliminate duplicates, which you probably don't want (and it's pretty convoluted compared to the other solutions).  Solutions by tommy.carstensen and Allan take pretty much the same amount of time to run.  The code you write is always more supportable if you are the only one who will see or maintain it, but if this code will be used by anyone else, I'd suggest using the solution from Allan as it is much more elegant to my eye.  Thanks tommy.carstensen for a well written and interesting problem :D